# Having a div stretch over previous div's position in CSS?

Tags: html, css

On http://www.gamefaqs.com/ , there's two divs next to each other, the content and the aside (poll). When you resize the window, eventually the poll gets knocked down to the bottom, but it doesn't leave any space and the content stretches over where the poll was.

I'm trying to do that but I just get empty space from where my aside is knocked down to.

Please refer to this picture for what I mean: http://imageshack.us/a/img37/4759/5tag.jpg

How do I make it act like GameFAQs site?

Here's my CSS

```
.container {
    width: 75%;
    overflow: auto;
    border: #FCC;
    border-style:double;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.container .content {
    background: #FFF;
    width: 75%;
    padding: 15px;
    float: left;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.container .archive {
    border:#3C9 thick;
    border-style:solid;
    background: #FFF;
    float:left;
    width:23%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-left:15px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: Look into css media queries. http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your `.archive` class and your `.content` to not be percentages of the parent because they will always fit side-by-side if they never get larger than their container (because they will always remain at 98% of the width.

You can do three different things to fix this:

1.) You can establish static values for those classes' widths.

2.) You can add this CSS:

```
.container .content {
  min-width: 600px;
}
.container .archive {
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

The `min-width` will stop the children from shrinking below your set size, therefore when the parent (`.container`) becomes too small to house their minimum sizes, the second `div` will then move down appropriately.

3.) You could look into using CSS3 Media Queries and responsive design strategies:

http://line25.com/tutorials/create-a-responsive-web-design-with-media-queries

Comment: +1 to responsive design methods. I've fallen in love with twitter's bootstrap framework and would also recommend it.